# PHP -slim catch uploaded file exception

Tags: php, slim

I am using slim to upload files like the following :

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    try {
        $fileLog = $file->moveTo($location));
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}

return true;
```

the problem i that there is probably a runtimeexception when there is no space in the disk and the phph trying to save the file.

I am looking for a way to always catch any exception with saving file :
no sapce, broken file ...etc

for now the issue is I cannot catch the runtime exception

Comment: Why do you catch an exception just to throw a new one?

Comment: to catch it in the next level . but this is not my question  :)

Comment: Even though this is not your question, are you aware that you don't need to do that? exceptions will bubble up automatically. The catch is pointless.

Comment: If you use a new enough PHP version you can have a look at catching throwables (http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) because that might catch the error as well.

Comment: Also check set_error_handler(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php